# Sylius installation on MAMP: inlt extention missing

Tags: mamp, sylius

Trying to install Sylius, I got these error.

[Errors trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JA730.png)

I could find how to install Intl for PHP5 but nothing for php 7.1.x.

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install php7.1-intl